# Why does one code produce a memory leak and the other doesn't?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Why does this code produce a memory leak? I'm a newbie and don't understand it. The object gets assigned to the shared_ptr so it's still accessible or not? I need to create the new instance in another function so I can't think of another way to do that. Is there anything I need to fix?

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass>newItem(getNewMyClassInstance());

MyClass* MyClass::getNewMyClassInstance()
{
    return new MyClass();
}
```

Also what is the difference between the above mentioned code and

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass>newItem(new MyClass());
```

regarding memory leaks?

Comment: Who told you it leads to memory leak?

Comment: A colleague when I showed them what I wrote.

Comment: I'm fairly new to C++ so I believed them and tried to find the error.

Comment: @annarama have faith in yourself and always confront challenges head on.  If there's a leak; you'll only learn if it's pointed out to you; so don't be afraid to say "where; how?"

Comment: @Caninonos: The OP is creating a `std::shared_ptr`.  The destructor of that will delete it for you when there are no outstanding references.  No need to remember anything (which is the whole point of `std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: @annarama: You ought to send your colleague back to C++ school!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a subtle difference.

Whenever the constructor of `MyClass` throws, `new MyClass();` does not produce any memory leak since the storage allocated for `MyClass` is [automatically freed by `new` when an exception is thrown](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Construction). In the snippets displayed in your question, none of the forms lead to memory leak.

But, if one would expand the definition of `getNewMyClassInstance()` in such a way than an exception is thrown at scope exit, your first form does lead to memory leak:

```
MyClass* MyClass::getNewMyClassInstance()
{
    ThrowsWhenDestructed t;
    return new MyClass();
}

std::shared_ptr<MyClass>newItem(getNewMyClassInstance());
// MyClass pointer is not acquired, and lost to oblivion.
```

With this form (a raw pointer returned by a function and then acquired by a smart pointer), there is a small gap where memory *could* be lost. Almost always this is not an issue, but it *might* be for you.

As an alternative, why won't you define:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> MyClass::getNewMyClassInstance()
{
    return std::make_shared<MyClass>();
}
```

Comment: So your answer is "if your code was actually <some other piece of code> then you'd have a memory leak"! ;p

Comment: (Your advice is sound though +1)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If it helps OP, it helps OP. If not, my answer says their code is OK, which helps OP. ;)

Comment: are you sure your alternative works? `clang++` complains about no viable conversion with all the `c++11`, `c++14` and `c++17` switches.

Comment: By the way, thank you for your answer. I hadn't thought about it before. Just tried with `valgrind` out of curiosity :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the alternative, I'll use that!

Comment: I think it would be better to rewrite the example without using a throwing destructor, since throwing destructors are in general a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

The point I suspect that someone is making is that by returning the shared pointer, you ensure that the pointer is always wrapped by a smart pointer.  By returning a naked pointer; this guarantee is lost; and thus leaves it more open to accidental leaks; ie

```
 { getNewMyClassInstance()->doStuff() }
```

will leak in one case; but not in the other.

However; the example usage you posted will not leak.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your code does not produce any memory leak. But to answer your second question:

- in the first form, it can produce a memory leak if you don't pay attention on the returned value of `getNewMyClassInstance()`. I mean you return a raw pointer then the caller may forget to free it correctly. You can return a shared pointer to have a better code.
- the first form is more like using a factory, which leads to more degree of freedom in the way instances are created.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these pieces of code creates a memory leak.

You have nothing to "fix".

Comment: Is'nt this better suited to a comment?

Comment: Really? Thank you so much! I thought I understood the whole memory allocation thing but then someone said my code was "wrong" and I couldn't understand why.

Comment: @SamerTufail an answer is an answer; not a comment.

Comment: @UKMonkey well what was said it could easily be covered in a comment. If this was probably someone with a lesser rep many would jump to to say what I have just said anyway. Win!

Comment: Fixed a typo in the answer, which also shortens it. +1.

Comment: @Bathsheba: That wasn't a typo; you made it grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @SamerTufail an answer that doesn't explain any of the whys is still an answer; (it might not be helpful; but it's still an answer).  That's why there's a downvote button.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'll run it past my mother, who's an English Literature Professor at Oxford.

Comment: What "why"s are you looking for? OP asserted that there is a memory leak; there isn't. End of story.

Comment: @Bathsheba: You do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Perhaps I better not. I'm already a black sheep.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Why am I not surprised :P

Comment: @SamerTufail: No. Comments are for requesting clarification, critiquing the question/answer and having silly arguments. They are not for providing answers/solutions, ever. That is what the answer section is for; it is literally the purpose of the answer section's existence. Length is irrelevant (though more detailed answers are of course sometimes better than shorter ones!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because silly arguments make this site the place it is ... :)

Comment: @UKMonkey: It really would not be the same without them 

Comment: I'm seeing my parents this weekend. Stack Overflow today has made me more tolerable in the eyes of my mother. Proving even the silliest exchanges have their uses.

Comment: @Bathsheba: An on-topic comment?? How _dare_ you! :)